# Unexpected "." at a discord.js, i didn't make this file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I've been working with the discord.js module in node.js, and it gives me a syntax error at a file i didn't make (the file is called discord.js/src/client/baseclient at line 45) when I run `npm run test` . The error goes like this:

```
D:\GhulamMuhammad\Programming\WebDev\Node.js\NeuralNode-Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js:45
        userAgentAppendix: options.rest?.userAgentAppendix
                                        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
←[90m    at Object.compileFunction (vm.js:344:18)←[39m
←[90m    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1048:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1082:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1022:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\GhulamMuhammad\Programming\WebDev\Node.js\NeuralNode-Bot\node_modules\←[4mdiscord.js←[24m\src\index.js:6:22)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)←[39m
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! NeuralNode-Bot@1.0.0 test: `node .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the NeuralNode-Bot@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SAAD\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-14T14_49_46_164Z-debug.log

D:\GhulamMuhammad\Programming\WebDev\Node.js\NeuralNode-Bot>‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎‎ ‎ ‎
```

I didn't make that file, so why is there an unexpected "." in it? Please let me know if any more information regarding my code is required..

Comment: It looks like a node version issue where it doesn't know what to do with `?.` - option chaining is unsupported prior to version 14

Comment: check your environment that code is run in. It uses the safe reference operator ``?.`` and your environment might not know that. (edit: It is called an optional chaining operator, the word I used is not "official")

Comment: yeah just having problems with node version... somehow using version 13

Comment: So install a newer one,

Comment: Just did that, problem solved :)